# Can this monitor be saved?

Tags: display

I've got this old monitor from my father. The image was ok for like 20 min, then it's like this. I've changed the DVI cable, but it didn't work. The image is like this even when the cable is not connected, so I guess it's the monitor itself. Is there something it can be done or it's garbage now? Thanks[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The engine in the monitor that turns signals into individual pixels on the screen has failed.

The repair would almost certainly cost more than a decent monitor.

So since (a) old and (b) broken, just replace it. That is the best course of action.